# Generating Map Tiles for MGRS Grid Graticule?

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, vector-grid, mgrs

I'm possibly a bit out of my league here, but ready to get my hands dirty.  I want to generate map tiles for a [MGRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_grid_reference_system) grid graticule similar to http://tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox/map/afghanistan-mgrs.

I need to create a function that takes a map boundary (probably something like two lat,lng pairs for the map corners) and the output image dimensions and returns an image.  I'm looking at using [Proj4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) to convert map coordinates to pixel coordinates.  I'm looking for some open source or starter code for calculating the MGRS grid lines.  Most libraries I've seen are for translating a single coordinate which is fine for calculating the grid cell, but I'm not sure how to get the grid cell boundaries/plot the grid lines.

I'm looking at this for a mobile application so something in Java or C/Objective-C is my end goal.

Can someone give me a push in the right direction?

---

**UPDATE**

Refining my requirements a bit here...

I need to create a function that returns a 256x256 image given lat,lng boundary and zoom level.  The zoom is a standard slippy map like zoom where the lowest zoom level is 1 which as 1 256x256 tile for the entire world and zoom level 2 has 4 tiles, and so on.  For each tile and corresponding zoom level, I would like to draw the MGRS grid graticule boundaries and add a MGRS center label at the center of the MGRS grid cell.

Comment: http://www.mappingsupport.com/p/recreation/coordinates_mgrs_topo_map.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are some ways for drawing a grid on a map. i havent tried them before bacause i have never needed it.

1.you can check out [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.github.com/) library for drawing grid on a map but it looks like a bit complex. it supports lots of projection.

you can find its doc [here](http://matplotlib.github.com/basemap/index.html) as Basemap Matplotlib Toolkit 1.0.3 documentation.

[image: matplotlib]

2.for qgis, you can try GridPluginLayer which overlays a user-definable grid on the map.. its source code [here](https://github.com/MerseyViking/gridoverlay/blob/d66ed86636c7ec3f02ca2e9298ac3086c2023f1d/gridpluginlayer.py).

3.in arcgis, you can use MakeGridsAndGraticulesLayer_cartography function for creating grid. you can get some information [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00700000001n000000).

> Syntax
>
> MakeGridsAndGraticulesLayer_cartography (in_template, in_aoi,
>   input_feature_dataset, output_layer, {name}, {refscale}, {rotation},
>   {mask_size}, {xy_tolerance}, {primary_coordinate_system},
>   {configure_layout}, {ancillary_coordinate_system_1},
>   {ancillary_coordinate_system_2}, {ancillary_coordinate_system_3},
>   {ancillary_coordinate_system_4})

4.with javascript, you can check out this example on google-map. there is some information in source code...

[image: google-map]

another javascript binding on google-maps [here](http://www.mappingsupport.com/p/gmap4.php?ll=39.626861,-104.942131&t=t1&z=10&coord=utm) with utm and i think it can help you so more from others...

Example Result:

```
Coordinates for point you clicked
Datum WGS84

UTM
Z13  454908,4451473

Decimal degrees:
Lat,Lon 40.212456,-105.5299
Lon,Lat -105.5299,40.212456
```

[image: grids]

i hope it helps you...

Comment: any idea what the usage license is on the last one?